# example for banning functions in $A.createComponent after Spring'19

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, spring19

Could someone share a piece of code that will stop working after the critical update "Prevent Creation of Function Expressions in Dynamically Created Aura Components" will be activated? 
I'm not quite sure what is being banned here. Passing inline code has never worked and passing references like this seems to work fine:

```
$A.createComponent(
        "ui:inputText",
                { "change": component.getReference("c.handleChange")},
                function(newCmp, status, errorMessage) {}
        );
```

Comment: yes, you can not send function expressions at $A.createComponent/$A.createComponents`   after summer 19  release check out here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278743/aura-component-critical-updates-related-to-a-createcomponent-or-a-createcomp. but in your case it should n't stop since your not passing any function

Comment: Thank you I did look before asking but somehow I missed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aura component critical updates related to $A.createComponent() or $A.createComponents()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278743/aura-component-critical-updates-related-to-a-createcomponent-or-a-createcomp)